# solve an exercise of two samples using Kolmogorov-smirnov

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm looking for books and information like crazy and I can not find what I need. Well the example proposed is about methods that have been used in literature students and these are the data collected:

$$
\begin{array}{rr}
\text{Method 1, “X"} & \text{Method 2, “Y"} \\
48      & 14      \\
40      & 18      \\
39      & 20      \\
50      & 10      \\
41      & 12      \\
38      & 102     \\
53      & 17     
\end{array}$$

calculate with a **level of significance** of $\alpha = 0.05$ and **P-Value**

Hypothesis

- $H_0 : F_{(t)} = G_{(t)}$
- $H_0 : F_{(t)} \neq G_{(t)}$

The null hypothesis indicates that there is
no difference between the reading groups X and Y.

I would like your help but as **I don't understand the development** well, I would ask you to do it **step by step**.

and I would also like to know how I solve an exercise where the samples **don't have the same size**

Comment: You need to use the self-study tag.

Comment: 1. What's your response variable there? 2. You ask about significance but your question contains no hypotheses; it's only a meaningful question in the presence of them. What's your null and alternative?

Comment: @Glen_b, edited

Comment: I presume F and G represent cdfs?

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks. I had to go look up how to do that in MathJax. The usual LaTex method didn't work.

Comment: @Glen_b : In the "answer" editing window, I typed &ldquo;, then copied the resulting rendered symbol, then pasted that into the MathJax code.  $\qquad$

Comment: Yep, thanks. I found a slightly different version of the trick but one with the same ultimate effect (the idea being to actually generate the required unicode character for the left double quote). Your approach is a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible tests for this situation.

A common choice is the two-sided [two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

Note that this assumes that the distributions are continuous; if your variables are discrete this test tends to be quite conservative (lower than desired type I error, with corresponding reduction in power)

As with the one-sample test, the test is based on the largest vertical distance between the cdfs.

This works with unequal sample sizes. There's a table of critical values at the link but any decent stats package will do it for you. You can

There's a small discrepancy between the table in Wikipedia and the p-values provided by R - the table values are large-sample, and are not exact for small samples. (You can find small sample tables fairly easily both in books and on-line.)